# verify webhook post signatures from Transnational webhook

Tags: c#, webhooks, .net-5

I trying to verify webhook post signatures from Transnational payments. there documentation for this is;

```
Webhook post requests are sent with a header "Signature" that is HMAC SHA 256 signed and then base64 url encoded.

To verify webhook post signatures, retrieve "Signature" from header. Base64 url decode and use HMAC SHA 256 to check using your signature UUID located in the control panel under the webhook previously created
```

First, when i try to Base64 Url decode the signature I get an error. here is an example of a Signature. "RwtK6Kr4NOOFs9mjYPpEJWxSJQr23k6uXDktj4QEjGk"

THere is the example code they use to test signature comparison: , I think it's in Go.

```
sig := r.Header.Get("Signature")
// Get the body
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
r.Body.Close()
// Verify Sig
mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte("signature-to-check-here"))
mac.Write(body)
sigCheck, _ := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(sig)
doesitequal := hmac.Equal(sigCheck, mac.Sum(nil))
ctx.Log().Infof("%v", doesitequal)
```

They also sent the code they use to encode the signature.

```
// Set webhook data into buffer for http post
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    enc := json.NewEncoder(buf)
    enc.SetEscapeHTML(true)
    enc.Encode(w.Data)
    // Encrypt the data for signature
    mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(w.Signature))
    mac.Write(buf.Bytes())
    base64Enc := base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(mac.Sum(nil))
    // Create post request
    client := &http.Client{
           Timeout: time.Duration(5 * time.Second),
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", w.URL, bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()))
    if err != nil {
           ctx.Log().AddField("Webhook data", w).Error(err.Error())
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Signature", base64Enc)
```

Here is 1 version of what I have tried. I'm trying to create the Signature from the response and match it to the signature in the header. I cannot get a match. this doesn't try

```
 Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;


        var client_secret = "[Secret]";

        //request body
        var body = "[Responce Body]";

        // signature form header
        var signature = "RwtK6Kr4NOOFs9mjYPpEJWxSJQr23k6uXDktj4QEjGk";

        // uri escape the body
        var calc_body = Uri.EscapeUriString(body);

        //url encode te body
        calc_body = WebUtility.UrlEncode(calc_body);

        //create the signature HMACSHA256    
        var sig = GenerateSignature(calc_body, client_secret);

        //Base64 Url encode the signture
        var calc_sig = Base64UrlEncode(ascii.GetBytes(sig));

        //Compare the signature form the header to the calculated cignature
        if (signature == calc_sig)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Matches");

        }
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Does not match");

        }
    }

    private static string GenerateSignature(string data, string signatureKey)
    {
        var keyByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureKey);
        using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
        {
            hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
            return hmacsha256.Hash.Aggregate("", (current, t) => current + t.ToString("X2")).ToLower();
        }
    }

    static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] arg)
    {
        var s = Convert.ToBase64String(arg); // Regular base64 encoder
        s = s.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
        s = s.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
        s = s.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
        return s;
    }
```

I'm not even sure I have the right steps.

Thanks in advance for any help.